# Best way to get exact proximity between devices

Tags: rf, nfc, bluetooth-low-energy

Need to get exact distance between devices like beacons or RF devices, exact means; about ~10cm tolerance.

Here is what I need;
I will use some devices like RF module or beacons on road and I need to make people with reciever walk on this road. The reciever that people have will communicate with these transmitter devices on the road. Transmistter and receiver has 0.5m to 3m distance and this distance will change while person was walking.

I made some search about BLE and RF and I saw getting distance by BLE is not reliable. [[Source1](http://blog.bluetooth.com/proximity-and-rssi/)]

In this [link](http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/propagation/path-loss/free-space-formula-equation.php) there are some calculations to find distance between RF devices, I can see result of even 1 cm distance change mathematically but can RF reciever take dB value decisively?

Most important part is here, this solution must be cheap and decisive, it should be feasible for indoor and outdoor, and shouldn't be more affected from noise and other factors

Lastly if RFID is suitable, can i communicate between transmitter on the floor with NFC on mobile phones from these distances.

Comment: I don't think you will find what you are looking for.  That "free space propagation formula" you linked to applies only in one case:  free space.  The presence of any other objects will influence the results.  In the simplest case, the presence of the human body, and the position of the transitter (or receiver) relative to the body, can drastically change the propagation of radio waves.

Comment: Why do you need (or want) this thing?  What goal are you trying to achieve?  Maybe there's a simpler (or more reliable or cheaper) way that would work well enough.

Comment: @JRE I explained the purpose in second paragraph, if it is not clear you can thing as <<make blind people walk on one destination with minimum deviation>>, Is BLE more safe?

Comment: That "make blind people walk to a destination with minimum deviation" is a start.  Can you describe what you are doing in more detail?

Comment: For example, you could setup a "fence" along the road that uses lasers and photodetectors.  If the laser is interrupted, then a buzzer sounds on that side of the road, so the person knows to veer over to the other side somewhat.  No radios involved.

Comment: it is not just one purpose, in my mind there is two project,
1) auto drive any device like mini car or drone in it's way
2) make blind people find their way in metro or open areas but not like follow black strip on floor.
I hope this explanation is enough.

Comment: If you are really dealing with blind people, consider making use of the capabilities they do have.  Set up a series of speakers generating sounds along side the road.  They can then center themselves on the road by keeping the sounds approximately even on each side.

Comment: For that fact, go completely low tech, and just run a ribbon along the road and let them follow it.  Hi tech isn't always better.

Comment: The road will be shared with other people, and blind people should walk in their own way like cars do in highway.

Comment: Just put up guide ropes on each side of the walkway.  The blind can follow the guides, and sighted people can walk around them.  Problem solved.

Comment: And, seriously.  I meant it with the sound.  Play pleasant music from speakers along the sides of the road.  The blind can follow along from speaker to speaker.

Comment: appreciated for your help, this solution should let blind people get on metro or tram, i dont want them get killed :) rope and sound is not appliable in this situation.

Comment: That's why I asked for more details.

Comment: Hmmm.  Blind people deal with that kind of thing all the time, without the aid of any radio equipment.  Maybe see how they manage to get around now before you invent something that isn't an improvement on how things alread work.

Comment: First I thought smart walking stick that detect black ribbon on road, but I want them to walk easier and faster. Thanks for good conversation :)

Comment: What you are asking for is very far from trivial, and today's tech simply isn't up to the task.  To bring the tech up to the task would require substantial R&D from very serious people, and maybe even a transformative way of thinking.  It's unlikely you will find your solution by asking people on the internet.  If this approach is central to your project, you might want to start thinking in a different way (as everyone is trying to tell you), because chances are you won't get very far this way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

BLE, RFID etc, these are all ways to **exchange data**, they're unsuited for location purposes !

Sure, EM waves take time to cover a distance, but take a moment to calculate what time we're talking about, it's a couple of ns. So your devices then need to be **time synchronised** by a couple of ns.

But it works for GPS ! Yes but what is the distance and accuracy there ? The distance is hundreds of km (distance between you and the satellites) and accuracy is 10m at best.

Signal strength is also not very well suited to measure distance. Sure theoretically it is easy but in practice it is not. The actual radiated and received power is not easy to measure accurately (and almost impossible with cheap equipment). Signals also reflect against other objects.

What might work is a device that transmits and receives **at the same time**, short range radar based solutions do that. Cheap short range radar solutions do not exist yet, but we're working on them ;-)

At the moment you're stuck with ultrasound based solutions.

Comment: I thought EM waves, Wifi Signals and GPS too, GPS is very unstable to accurate distance and it is not available in underground, I did afraid from EM signals for health but i will continue to search for it, Radar is really expensive, we talk about 150$ budget for each reciever and ~5$ for transmitter device. I have no idea about ultrasound but i think it can be affected from environment. It seems there is no solution so I will mark this answer as solution. If you have any idea to clarify me please comment this.

Comment: Your comments on GPS are factually wrong, and quite misleading in terms of what they imply about local time-of-flight systems - especially as local references are how GPS can be many orders of magnitude better than you think.

Comment: @ChrisStratton *especially as local references* I know and I was not talking about that, I was talking about GPS on it's own. I also know GPS uses triangulation but that still does nothing for what OP wants. But if you know it better then please explain so we can all learn something.